# how to test on smartphone application on notebook: connection issue

Tags: 14.04, networking, android

I am developing a `Ruby on Rails` application and I would like to see how it behaves on smartphone. I checked in Internet and found that to connect my smartphone to the server running on my notebook, I have to write on the address bar of the browser on my smartphone the local IP address of my notebook followed by colon and the port of the server: `192.168.1.5:1234`
Both smartphone and notebook are on the same wifi network

However the connection results not available.
I wonder if I have to change some firewall settings or else.
According to a [railcast](http://railscasts.com/episodes/199-mobile-devices?autoplay=true) and [a conversation on Stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4779963/how-can-i-access-my-localhost-from-my-android-device) the process should be straightforward, so I do not understand why I am unable to connect. I suppose that I should be prompted for my username and password, but nothing happens, the attempt lasts for some time then fails.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is necessary to add a rule on your firewall to allow incoming connections on port 1234:

```
$ sudo ufw allow 1234
```

Or better allow by IP address and port:

```
$ sudo ufw allow from 192.168.1.2 to any port 1234
```